# Creating a Tic Tac Toe with 4x4 grid, cout and endl unidentified?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Here is the code, i am a beginner at coding and do not know how to find out the errors after following various different tutorials. I keep coming up with errors as 'cout' and 'endl' are undeclared identifiers.

```
#include <iostream>
#define ORDER 4
void PrintGrid(char [ORDER][ORDER]);
bool CheckGrid( char [ORDER][ORDER]);
int main(void){
    char grid[ORDER][ORDER] ;
    int j,k,l;
    for(j=0;j<ORDER;j++)
        for(k=0;k<ORDER;k++)
            grid[j][k]=' ';
    grid[2][3]='X';
    PrintGrid(grid);
    return 0;
}
void PrintGrid(char g[ORDER][ORDER]){
    for (int j=0;j<ORDER;j++){
        for(int l=0;l<2*ORDER +1;l++)
            cout << '-';
        cout << endl <<'|';
        for (int k=0;k<ORDER;k++)
            cout << g[j][k] <<'|';
        cout << endl;
    }
    for(int l=0;l<2*ORDER +1;l++)
        cout << '-';
    cout << endl;
}
bool CheckGrid( char g[ORDER][ORDER]){
    // check horiz
    // untested
    int k,j;
    for( k=0;k<ORDER;k++){
        for( j=1;j<ORDER;j++)
            if(g[0][k]!=g[k][j]) break;
        if(j==ORDER) return true;
    }

    for( k=0;k<ORDER;k++){
        for( j=1;j<ORDER;j++)
            if(g[k][0]!=g[k][j]) break;
        if(j==ORDER) return true;
    }

    for( k=0;k<ORDER;k++){
        if(g[0][0]!=g[k][k]) break;
        if(k==ORDER) return true;
    }
    for( k=0;k<ORDER;k++){
        if(g[0][ORDER-1]!=g[ORDER-k][ORDER-k]) break;
        if(k==ORDER) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Tabs. Convert them to spaces before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cout` and `endl` are in the `std` namespace. You have to reference them like this:

```
std::cout << ... << std::endl;
```

unless you are `using` them:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

You can also include the whole namespace:

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Okay thank you. whenever i run it the window just closes immediately ?

Comment: @Shauna there are other questions that address that issue already. Use the search feature.